# Rudin's RCA theorem $4.2$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

There is the definition which we need for the proof of the theorem:
[image]
There is the theorem:
[image]

I don't understand in the proof of The Schwarz inequality how is it guaranteed that  there is a complex number $\alpha$ such that

$|\alpha|$ $=$ $1$ and $\alpha$$(y,x)$ $=$ $B$.

Hence I also don't  understand Why is $-r$($\alpha(y,x)$ + $\bar\alpha$$(x,y)$) equal of $-2Br$. ( Look at inequality $(2)$ ).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: suppose $$\alpha (y,x)=B$$ we know that $\alpha$ exists because we can assume $(y,x)$ to be nonzero (if it was zero, the inequality holds trivially). So we can multiply B by the inverse of $(y,x)$ and obtain $\alpha$. We also know that $$|\alpha\cdot (y,x)|=B \implies |\alpha||(y,x)|=B$$ and because $B=|(x,y)|=|(y,x)|$, we gain $|\alpha|=1$$$$$ For the second part, just factor out r and use the above properties to get to the result.

Comment: @Fix so we should have $\alpha(y,x)$ + $\bar\alpha$$(x,y)$ = $2B$ that means that $(x, \alpha y)$ should be equal of $B$ too . I don't undnerstand how does it follow from the above properties

Comment: If $(y,x)=0,$ let $\alpha =1.$ If $(y,x)\ne 0$ then $\alpha =\frac {|(y,x)|}{(y,x)}.$ If $0\ne z\in\Bbb C$ then $\left|\frac {|z|}{z}\right|=1.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet yes that's answer on the first question. Can you please answer on the second question?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Why is $-r$($\alpha(y,x)$ + $\bar\alpha$$(x,y)$) equal of $-2Br$. ( Look at inequality $(2)$ ).

Comment: I  understand it now  thank u

Comment: $\alpha (y,x)=B=|(y,x)|\in\Bbb R$. And $\overline {\alpha}(x,y)=\overline {\alpha}\cdot \overline {(y,x)}=\overline {\alpha (y,x)}=\overline B.$ And $\overline B=B$ because $B\in\Bbb R.$ BTW the last 2 sentences of the proof in the book can be improved: If $A,B,C\in\Bbb R$ and if $\forall r\in\Bbb R\,(A-2Br+Cr^2\ge 0)$ then $B^2\le AC.$ We need not consider the cases $C=0$ or $C\ne 0$ separately.

Comment: In the cases $H=\Bbb C^n$ or $H=\Bbb R^n$ with $2\le n\in\Bbb N$, there is a direct proof: Let $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,...,y_n)$ be in $H$. Let $x'=(|x_1|,...,|x_n|)$ and $y'=(|y_1|,...|y_n|).$ Then $\|x\|\cdot\|y\|= \|x'\|\cdot\|y'\|$ and $|(x,y)|\le |(x',y')|$ so it suffices to prove $\|x'\|\cdot\|y'\| \ge  |(x',y')|.$ This is immediate from the identity  $(\|x'\|\cdot\|y'\|)^2=$ $(\sum_i (x'_i)^2)( \sum_j (y'_j)^2)=$ $(\sum_k x'_ky'_k)^2+\sum\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}(x'_iy'_j-x'_jy'_i)^2=$ $|(x,y)|^2|+\sum\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}(x'_iy'_j-x'_jy'_i)^2.$

Comment: In the last line of my previous comment, $|(x,y)|^2|$ should be $|(x',y')|^2.$